# variables in templates (django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm using an LDAP backend to authenticate users. After the user is logged in the following view is displayed:

views.py:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

index.html contains the following part:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="/link1/">Link 1</a> | <a href="/link2/">Link 2</a> | <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>  ({{ user.username }})
{% else %}
<a href="/login/">Login</a><br />
{% endif %}
```

{{ user.username }} displays the sAMAccountName of the user defined in ldap.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SYNC, SIMPLE, SUBTREE
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError


class LDAPBackend(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.domain = settings.AD_DNS_NAME


    def authenticate(self, username = None, password = None):

        username = username.lower()
        if not self.is_valid(username, password):
            return None

        try:
            self.s = Server(self.domain, port = 636, use_ssl = True, get_info = ALL)
            self.c = Connection(self.s, auto_bind = True,
                            client_strategy = SYNC,
                            user = username, password = password,
                            authentication = SIMPLE,
                            check_names = True)

        except LDAPBindError:
            return False

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username = username)           
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            result = self.c.extend.standard.paged_search(search_base = settings.AD_BASE_DN,
                        search_filter = "(sAMAccountName = %s)" % username,
                        search_scope = SUBTREE,
                        attributes = settings.AD_USER_ATTR,
                        paged_size = 5,
                        generator = False)

            if result[3]["attributes"]["givenName"]:
                first_name = result[3]["attributes"]["givenName"]
            else:
                first_name = None

            if result[3]["attributes"]["sn"]:
                last_name = result[3]["attributes"]["sn"]
            else:
                last_name = None

            if result[3]["attributes"]["mail"]:
                email = result[3]["attributes"]["mail"]
            else:
                email = None

            user = User(username = username,
                    first_name = first_name,
                    last_name = last_name,
                    email = email)

            user.is_staff = False
            user.is_superuser = False
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

    return user


def is_valid (self, username = None, password = None):

    if password == None or password == "":
        return False


def get_user(self, user_id):

    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk = user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I'd like to make a function that searches for certain attribute in LDAP and return the results as a list. The question is how is the variable defined in the template file, like {{ user.username }}, if the function is in ldap.py. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should pass a context dictionary including your variables to the template. The variables (like `user`) do not _magically_ appear in templates. They are passed through context, either from your view or by a middleware.

Comment: thank you. That's what I did and it works.